# How to properly fit a graph in rmarkdown editor and knitted html document?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, visualization

I am creating some plots that have some alignment issues in rmarkdown editor & html documents.

Graph is not aligning in center even on using `fig.align='center'` and its also cutting out at edges (PS in attached image: names of the countries have been cut out on left side).

How can I have the **chart scrollable on x axis** rather than cutting out or scaling down as that makes it unreadable.

For example charts on this webpage is scrollable rather than scaled down: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gapminder/README.html

**Use of chunk settings is shown in below image:**
[image]

**I have also used these chunk settings**:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, dpi = 300, cache = FALSE, attr.output='style="max-height: 300px;"')`

**Issue of country names getting cut out is shown in below image**
[image]

**Code for Ref.**

```
library(tidyverse)

gapminder <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/swcarpentry/r-novice-gapminder/gh-pages/_episodes_rmd/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv")

gapminder <- gapminder %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)

gapminder_gdpPercap_diff  <- gapminder %>% 
                              filter(year %in% c(1952,2007)) %>% 
                              
                              # filter(country %in% c("India","Vietnam")) %>% 
                              
                              arrange(country, year) %>% 
                              
                              group_by(country) %>% 
                              
                              mutate(gdpPercap_diff = gdpPercap[2] - gdpPercap[1],
                                     max_pop = max(pop)) %>% 
                              
                              ungroup() %>% 
                              
                              arrange(gdpPercap_diff) %>% 
                              
                              filter(max_pop > 30000000) %>% 
                              
                              mutate(country = droplevels(country)) %>% 
                              select(country, year, continent, gdpPercap, gdpPercap_diff)

gapminder_gdpPercap_diff %>% 
  mutate(country = fct_inorder(country)) %>% 
  
  group_by(country) %>% 
  
  mutate(max_gdpPercap = max(gdpPercap),
         min_gdpPercap = min(gdpPercap)) %>% 
  
  ungroup() %>% 

 # plotting begins
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = min_gdpPercap, xend = max_gdpPercap,
                   y = country, yend = country,
                   col = continent), alpha = 0.5, size = 7) +
  
  geom_point(aes(x = gdpPercap, y = country, col = continent), size = 8, alpha = .8) +
  
  geom_text(aes(x = min_gdpPercap + 10, y = country,
                label = paste(country, round(min_gdpPercap))),
            col = "grey50", hjust = "right") +
  
  geom_text(aes(x = max_gdpPercap - 8.0, y = country,
                label = round(max_gdpPercap)),
            col = "grey50", hjust = "left") +
  
  # scale_x_continuous(limits = c(20,85)) +
  
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
  
  labs(title = "Change in GDP Per Capita",
       subtitle = "Between years 1952 and 2007",
       col = "Continent") +
  
  # background & theme settings
  theme_classic() +
  
  theme(legend.position = "top", 
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank()
        )
```

If I add `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1000,35000))` as suggested in answers then chart becomes too small to read country names & figures (see image below). I would like the chart to be readable even if I have scroll for that.

[image]

Comment: Here is the Rmd code from the link you posted https://github.com/jennybc/gapminder/blob/master/README.Rmd

Comment: I have checked their code but they don't seem to be using any different chunk options that is making the difference. I have also tried with `out.width = "100%"` but that didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do new scale_x_continuous, but use expand instead of limits,`scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.25)))` worked for me.

Comment: Thanks alot @Kat. It's exactly what I was looking for !!

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to what you wanted. `scale_x_continuous` can be set manually to deal with visibility. You have commented it in your code.

Try `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5000,40000))` and you can adjust based on your satisfaction.

Comment: with `scaling_x_continuous()` the chart looks so small that **Country names & figures** becomes unreadable which I may be able to fix by increasing font size but that will make them overlap. I guess I will prefer a good size chart which can be scrolled and is readable. I have added the result chart image for scale_x_continuous().